# How do I enforce exception handling in the condition of a for loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to loop the object check which is a specific database obtained from the OpenLCA software. This database has a certain bug in some instance of it. Whenever I am running the for statement, after looping through many instances, when the code encounters buggy instance it throws me a error in the for loop condition -

for i in check:

How do I enforce exception handling on the for loop condition statement as shown. Please help.

Just to be very specific - t**he error is not thrown for the statement inside the loop. Its thrown in  `for i in check` statement itself. So having try inside the loop does not help me for this case.**

```
    check = client.get_all(olca.Process)
    for i in check:
       #print(type(i))
       process = i.default_allocation_method
       name = i.name
       print(name)
```

File "U:/Desktop/Box/Box Sync/Research_compile/electricitylci/pythonapiopenlca.py", line 101, in 
    for i in check:

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\olca\ipc.py", line 105, in get_all
    e.from_json(r)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\olca\schema.py", line 1882, in from_json
    self.default_allocation_method = AllocationType(val)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py", line 291, in **call**
    return cls.**new**(cls, value)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py", line 533, in **new**
    return cls.*missing*(value)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py", line 546, in *missing*
    raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.**name**))

ValueError: 'NO_ALLOCATION' is not a valid AllocationType

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really a way to isolate a `try` to only cover the `for` statement. Perhaps wrap it something like this:

```
def wrap_next(getter):
    while True:
        try:
           yield getter.next()
        except ValueError:
            howl(misery, desperation)

for i in wrap_next(check) 
    ... Do things
```

Answer (score 2):

use `try` and `except` inside your `for` loop like this:

```
for i in check:
   try:
       process = i.default_allocation_method
       name = i.name
       print(name)
   except Exception as e:
       print("error is: {}".format(e))
```

**UPDATE**: If your error raised in `for` loop statement and you want to continue your for loop execution even after error was raise, you can replace it with `while` loop (if `check` has `len` and is not an iterator) and handle exceptions like this:

```
check = client.get_all(olca.Process)
i = 0
while i < len(check):  # or other function that returns length of check
    try:
        process = check[i].default_allocation_method
        name = check[i].name
        print(name)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error is: {}".format(e))
    finally:
        i += 1
```

if `check` is an iterator you can use generator function (see @tripleee answer)

Comment: Perfect, especially if the individual just wants to continue on after :)

Comment: The error is not coming in the statements inside the loop. My error is raised in the statement `for in check:` Doing what you suggested is not helping me in this situation.

Comment: @TapajyotiGhosh then where it is come? what exactly is your error ?

Comment: @shotgunner The error is thrown in the statement - ``for i in check:`` This statement calls some code inside the module I am using which raises a ValueError.

Comment: @TapajyotiGhosh. then why you don't put `try` and `except` outside the for loop ?

Comment: @shotgunner Tried that. What happens in that case is that once the error is encountered, the entire loop stops. The code doesn't throw an error. I want  the loop to keep on continuing even if the error occurs in the for conditional statement.

Comment: @TapajyotiGhosh is `check` variable a list ? can you use `len(check)` in your code ?

Comment: Ok I was able to solve my problem by editing the module core files I was using. Its not a direct solution to the problem I mentioned in the question. The question can be closed. @shotgunner I basically used exception handling withing the core module files and it helped. Thank you so much.

Comment: it sounds to me like your design pattern/coding up to the point of the loop is lacking, I would modify that as opposed to source code of a library that you installed

Comment: @TapajyotiGhosh You can replace your `for` loop with `while` to handle that. see my updated answer.

Comment: @shotgunner your updated version will not work if `client.get_all(olca.Process)` returns an iterator.